# Calculate distance between points drawn on different zoomscale

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, zooming, distance

I'm developing an iPhone app where the user chooses an image and then is allowed to draw on it (dots) that maybe stored on different zoomscales (he's allowed to zoom in and out).

I store the location of every point drawn in an array but when I calculate the distance I come to realize the result isn't correct if the points were stored on different zoomscales. Would someone kindly help me with this?

Comment: then try by storing the point and the zoom scale using Dictionary or something and draw according to the zoom scale ..

Comment: I am doing so in a different array, forgot to mention that. But I don't know what to do next? how do I get all the points to reflect values of the same zoomscale? should I divide the points by their zoomscale?

Comment: Mr. @barley has directed you the way. try it

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should store points in normalized unit.

Assuming that you are using `UIScrollView` for zooming, divide both x and y by current `scrollView.zoomScale` before storing. When calculating the distance, multiply the distance back by `scrollView.zoomScale`.